# Solving $f'=0$ in distribution sense

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

When we solve $f'=0$, we can solve it by using Fourier transform in the space of tempered distribution to get $$i\xi\hat{f}(\xi)=0,$$ which gives us the distribution $\hat{f}(\xi)=0$, thus $f=0$. However, the solution is $f=const$. I want to know what is the problem

Comment: $\hat{f(\xi)}=0$ only for $\xi\neq 0$, else you omit $\delta$ whose Fourier transform is $1$ (leading to constants).

Comment: Also to avoid the Fourier transform : $f'=0$ as distributions means for any $\phi \in C^\infty_c, f \ast \phi \in C^\infty$ and $ 0 = f' \ast \phi = (f \ast \phi)'$  thus $f \ast \phi$ is constant. With $\int \phi=1$ and $\phi_n(x) =n \phi(nx)$ you obtain $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f \ast \phi_n$ is constant.

Comment: @zwim thanks. the support of a distribution is $0$ gives that the function is a combination of $delta$ function and its derivative.

Comment: If $T$ is a distribution of order $m$ supported on $K$ then $|<T,\phi>| \le C\sum_{n\le m} \sup_{x \in K} |\phi^{(n)}(x)|$. If $K= \{0\}$ then $|<T,\phi>| \le C\sum_{n\le m} \sup_{x \in K} |\phi^{(n)}(0)|$ so that $<T,\phi - \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{\phi^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n> = 0$ and $<T,\phi> = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{\phi^{(n)}(0)}{n!} <T,x^n>$ ie. $T = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n\delta^{(n)}$ with $a_n= (-1)^n\frac{<T,x^n>}{n!}$

Answer (score 3):

The distributional solutions to $i\xi \, \hat{f}(\xi) = 0$ are $\hat{f}(\xi) = C \, \delta(\xi),$ where $C$ is a constant.

This is in accordance with the solutions to $f'(x) = 0,$ which are $f(x) = C \, 1(x),$ transforming to $\hat{f}(\xi) = C \, 2\pi\,\delta(\xi).$

---

I will now show that the distributions satisfying $x \, u(x) = 0$ are $u(x) = C \, \delta(x)$ for constant $C$.

Let $u$ be a tempered distribution such that $x \, u(x) = 0$ and fix a test function $\rho$ such that $\rho(0) = 1.$ Set $C = \langle u, \rho \rangle.$

Given an arbitrary test function $\phi$ set $\hat{\phi} = \phi - \phi(0)\,\rho.$ Then $\hat{\phi}$ is a test function and $\hat{\phi}(0) = 0.$ There then exists a test function $\psi$ such that $\hat{\phi}(x) = x \, \psi(x).$

Now we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle u, \phi \rangle
&= \langle u, \hat{\phi} + \phi(0) \, \rho \rangle \\
&= \langle u, \hat{\phi} \rangle + \phi(0) \, \langle u, \rho \rangle \\
&= \langle u, x \, \psi \rangle + \phi(0) \, C \\
&= \langle x \, u, \psi \rangle + C \langle \delta, \phi \rangle \\
&= \langle 0, \phi \rangle + \langle C \, \delta, \phi \rangle \\
&= \langle C \, \delta, \phi \rangle.
\end{align}$$
Since this is true for any test function $\phi$ we have $u = C \, \delta,$ where $C$ is a constant (which here depends on the choice of $\rho$).