# How to solve distributional equations?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve this exercise

If $T \cdot x=1$ in the sense of distributions then $T=\textrm{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+c \delta_{0}$

Where $\delta_{0}$ is the Dirac delta distribution centered at the origin and $$\left\langle\textrm{p.v.}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), \varphi\right\rangle=\lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R} \backslash(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} d x$$

For any test function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Here's my attempt, equality in the distribution sense must mean equality for any test function, so

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}T\cdot x \varphi dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi dx \implies \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi (T \cdot x - 1)dx = 0 \implies \int_\mathbb{R} x\varphi (T - \frac{1}{x})dx = 0$$

Since $\varphi$ is any arbitrary test function $\psi = x \varphi$

$$\implies \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)} \psi (T - \frac{1}{x})dx + \int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \psi (T - \frac{1}{x})dx = 0$$

Taking $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ gives

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}T\psi = \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R} \backslash(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)} \frac{\psi(x)}{x} d x$$

So $T$ is the Cauchy principal value. But where does the dirac delta appear? If I know nothing about $T$ is it justified to assume that $\langle T, \varphi \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} T\varphi$ i.e. "integral of something" times the test function? The dirac delta does not seem to really follow example as its just defined as $\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle = \varphi(0)$, nor does the principal value.

Comment: The $\textrm{pv}$ or $\textrm{p.v.}$ is short for "principal value"; it's not a multiplication.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: So why do you write it as a multiplication, $\mathrm{p} \cdot \mathrm{v} \cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$?

Comment: The Dirac delta comes in as the solutions to the homogeneous equation $T \cdot x = 0.$ If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two solutions to $T \cdot x = 1$ then $T_1$ and $T_2$ differ by a solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: My latex is still a bit primitive.

Comment: Is differing to a solution to the homogeneous equation analogous to function equality almost everywhere differing at a null set or solutions to linear problems differing by an element in the kernel? Does this apply to any equality in the sense of distributions?

Comment: It's analogous to "solutions to linear problems differing by an element in the kernel". It has nothing to do with null sets. I wouldn't say that it applies to "any" equality. It applies to solving linear equations; multiplication with $x$ is a linear operator on the space of distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So $T$ is the Cauchy principal value. But where does the dirac delta appear?

The Dirac delta comes in as the solutions to the homogeneous equation $T \cdot x=0$. If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two solutions to $T \cdot x=1$ then $T_1$ and $T_2$ differ by a solution to the homogeneous equation.

> If I know nothing about $T$ is it justified to assume that $\langle T,
> \varphi \rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} T\varphi$ i.e. "integral of
>   something" times the test function?

No, it is not. The distribution doesn't have to be a function. For example, $\delta$ is not a function.

Because of this your solution is not good.

I'd like to suggest another approach:

1. Show that $x \cdot \textrm{p.v.}\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1$ as a distribution.
2. Then add the solutions to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: How do I show that $T \cdot x = 0$ has unique solution $T = \delta_0$? Since I can't assume being able to express as an integral I have $\langle T\cdot x, \varphi \rangle = 0 = \langle T, x \varphi \rangle $ for any test function.

Comment: Actually I do not think I can say $\langle T\cdot x, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, x \varphi \rangle $ since I am implicitly using commutativity of functions underneath the integral.

Comment: By definition of $T \cdot x$ you have $\langle T \cdot x, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, x \varphi \rangle$.

Comment: Perhaps you have showed in the course that $x \delta = 0$?

Comment: Could you explain why $\langle T\cdot x, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, x \varphi \rangle $ is by definition? I haven't had the product of smooth functions and distributions formally defined so it might be obvious, unfortunately I have not seen the proof $x \delta = 0$, this is an exercise from my PDE course where distributions were a somewhat brief aside to rigorously define fundamental solutions so I haven't seen much, if any, manipulations involving them.

Comment: Multiplication of a $C^\infty$ function $f$ with a distribution $T$ is defined through
$$\langle f T, \varphi \rangle := \langle T, f \varphi \rangle.$$
This is based on that this is valid when $T$ is a function:
$$\int (f T)(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx = \int T(x) \, (f\varphi)(x) \, dx$$

Comment: It's easy to see that $x \delta = 0$:
$$\langle x \delta, \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta, x \varphi \rangle = (x \varphi)(0) = 0 \varphi(0) = 0 = \langle 0, \varphi \rangle.$$
To see why $T = C \delta$ for $C$ constant are the only distributional solutions to $x T = 0$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3172467/168433.

Comment: Makes sense thanks.