# Solve $xu = f$ distributionally, for $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> I would like to solve the distributional equation $$xu = f, $$ where $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $u$ is a compactly supported tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have been told that the general solution to this equation is $$u = a \delta_0 + b \cdot \mathrm{p.v.}\frac{1}{x} + c, $$ where $a, b$ are constants and $c$ is some smooth function. However, I do not know how to prove this.

From the answer of this question [How to solve distributional equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174569/how-to-solve-distributional-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1), we have that the solution to my equation would be the sum of the general solution to the homogenous equation and the inhomogenous equation. The homogenous equation $$ xu = 0 $$ is solved by $a \delta_0$ where $a$ is a constant. However, I do not know how to continue from here.

Alternatively, by the Paley-Wiener theorem, we know that the Fourier transform of $u$ is a smooth function with some particular decay.
Hence, if we take the Fourier transform of the equation, we get that $$i(\mathcal{F}u)' = \mathcal{F}f,$$ but I do not know how to solve this equation dsitributionally and conclude from here.

Comment: If $f$ is not compactly supported, then there is no solution. For $f$ compactly supported, do you mean $PV(f(x)/x)$, rather than just $PV(1/x)$? ... this is compactly supported only when $f$ is. And constants are not compactly supported, of course... Can you clarify?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes you are right, $f$ should be compactly supported, I will edit this. As for the principal value part, it is possible that I may have misunderstood the solution that I have been told. Indeed, $PV(f(x)/x)$ does solves the equation.

Comment: But then, using the reference I have provided in the question, this would imply that the general solution of the equation is $$u = a \delta_0 + PV(f(x)/x), $$ is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd think that $a\cdot \delta+PV(f(x)/x)$ is the general solution, since the only solutions to $xu=0$ are $a\cdot \delta$.

Comment: I agree that that is the general solution. The term $b \operatorname{pv}\frac1x$ would give a constant term for $xu$.