# Question about a property of generalized functions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let V be a finite dimensional real vector spaces of dimension n with basis $e_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. We denote by $x_i$ the coordinate function, namely the function that associate to $v = v_1e_1+...+v_ne_n \in V $ the element $v_i$.
Let P be another finite dimensional real vector space. We set $W= V \oplus P $ and denote by $C^{-\infty}(W)$ the set of generalized function over W.

I find the following statement in the proof  of lemma 21 in the article by Kumar and Vergne on  equivariant cohomology with generalized coefficients :

If $x_if(x+y)=0$, for all i. Then f is the product of the $ \delta$-function on V with a generalized function on P .

Why this is true?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First get rid of the vector space language and symbols like $\oplus$ etc. This is just multivariate calculus, but with a distributional twist. You have a distribution $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_p)$ in $n+p$ variables which satisfies $x_i f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_p)=0$ for for all $i$, $1\le i\le n$. First look at $n=1$ and $p=0$. This is done in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172353/solving-f-0-in-distribution-sense/3172467#3172467 then add more variables and see how to adapt that method.

Comment: Hi! I'm interested in this question. Can anyone please one explain to me what does it mean that $f$ is the product of the $\delta-$function on $V$ with a generalized function on $P$, how is  this product defined?